# "Can't find the insertSheet function" error after updating code to use advanced google services

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have just updated my script to use the new advanced google services. In this case i have inserted a file in a folder, and now i need to format the file: insert sheets, change colors, etc.

I am having problems for working the file because after using this service I cannot get the file to work with it, i get this error:

> "Can't find the insertSheet function in the object FileIterator".

If you can head me to a place where I can find a solution, it would be very helpful.

This is the code i am using:

```
function HAR() {
//This is the new part of the code...
var name = "Template";
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("HAR");
var folder_id = folder.getId();
var resource = {
    title: name,
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{ id: folder_id }]
  }
var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource);
var File_id = fileJson.id;
var Template = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Template");// I guess this is not working
//This is the old part of the code...
const ssNames = ["California","Arizona","Florida","Los Angeles"];
const states = ssNames.length;
var x;
    for (x = 0; x < sNames.length; x++){
    Template.insertSheet(sNames[x]); //I can't manage to insert the sheets
    }
Template.getSheetByName("Sheet 1").activate();
Template.deleteActiveSheet(); 
}
```

Comment: `Template` is a FileIterator.  So it's been assigned a value, but your code doesn't show `Template` being assigned a value, so you must have other code that you haven't shown.  FileIterator only has 3 methods available to it, `getContinuationToken()` `hasNext()` and `next()`  You probably want to insert a sheet into the newly created spreadsheet file.  `var File_id = fileJson.getId(); var newSS_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(File_id);`

Comment: Sandy, thanks a lot for your quick response. You were right, i omitted a part of the code by mistake. My bad.

I tried your suggestion and it worked perfect.

Thank you bro.

Comment: @AlanWells - just chanced upon the question - would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Comment: @AlanWells - was passing by and did not want to make a CW answer before pinging you, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`Template` is a `FileIterator.` So it's been assigned a value, but your code doesn't show `Template` as being assigned a value, so you must have other code that you haven't shown.

`FileIterator` only has 3 methods available to it:

- `getContinuationToken()`
- `hasNext()`
- `next()`

You probably want to insert a sheet into the newly created spreadsheet file.

```
var File_id = fileJson.getId();
var newSS_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(File_id);
```